# TFS 2010 - Burndown and Burn Rate Report - Missing Iteration & Areas

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

This question has been asked once before but it got no answers so I am asking it again.

We are running TFS 2010 and have started to put a lot of work items in there.  We have an iteration hierarchy set up, several areas defined, and work items assigned to each, but when I go to try and run the 'Burndown and Burn Rate Report' none of my Iterations or Areas are available in the drop down list.

The 'Burndown and Burn Rate', 'Remaining Work', and 'Unplanned Work' reports exhibit this behavior but the rest of the default Project Management reports populate those drop downs correctly.  Here is an image showing the behavior:

[image]

The only thing the problem reports have in common are that they use the data source that points to the Tfs_Analysis analysis service in addition to the normal Tfs_Warehouse data source.  I have tried right clicking Tfs_Analysis in SQL Server Management Studio, clicking 'Process', and going through that procedure, as well as restarting the "Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent" service but neither have helped.

Has anyone encountered this issue and manage to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow...see what happens sometimes when you actually have to pose a question with enough detail to have someone help you?  Here is what I did to get it working:

1. On the server TFS is running on, go to the TFS instance's WarehouseControlWebService (http://:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx)
2. Click 'BringAnalysisProcessingOnline'
3. Click 'Invoke'
4. This should open up a new tab with some XML whose value is 'Started'.
5. Go back to the main page
6. Click 'ProcessAnalysisDatabase'
7. Enter 'Full' for the 'processingType' parameter
8. Click 'Invoke'
9. This should open up a new tab with some XML whose value is 'true'.

I have captured a [screencast here](http://screencast.com/t/SWmvI0nB) for anyone who may be interested, and there is a [helpful MSDN article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).